# Error 'Character set '#255' in Mysql Replication

Tags: mysql, master-slave

I did master slave replication but getting below error

Last_Error: Error 'Character set '#255' is not a compiled character set and is not specified in the '/usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml' file' on query. Default database: 'xyz'. Query: 'BEGIN'

Slave Mysql Version: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.36, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
Master Mysql Version: mysql  Ver 8.0.22 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by an inconsistency in the character set versions of primary and secondary mysql.
you can use a `SHOW CHARACTER SET;` Command to view the difference in character sets

such as:mysql 5.7.30  use `SHOW CHARACTER SET;` Command

```sql
Charset| Description    | Default collation  | Maxlen |
utf8mb4 UTF-8 Unicode   utf8mb4_general_ci  4
```

such as:mysql 8.0 use `SHOW CHARACTER SET;` Command

```sql
Charset  | Description     | Default collation   | Maxlen |
utf8mb4  | UTF-8 Unicode   | utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci  |      4
```

The collation between the two of them is inconsistent

solution: change your mysql version